# Passing arguments to Bash Script to use with a command

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I have an iOS Build command on Mac and I want to create a script that will receive arguments like iOS version, Device etc and run a build with it.
For some reason I am unable to pass the arguments successfully from the cmd to the script itself.
Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
DEVICENAME="iPhone 5s"
OS="9"
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,OS=9.2' -project /Users/etc/etc/Application.xcodeproj
```

I tried substituting like this:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=$DEVICENAME,OS=$OS' -project /Users/etc/etc/Application.xcodeproj
```

And like this:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=${DEVICENAME},OS=${OS}' -project /Users/etc/etc/Application.xcodeproj
```

Neither works and I can't seem to find a fix online.
Anybody knows what should I do here?

Comment: This is the [difference between single and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't put variables in single quotes, so it should be:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=$DEVICENAME,OS=$OS" -project /Users/etc/etc/Application.xcodeproj
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this once I'm near my computer

Comment: When I run the command in the Mac shell I run it with single quotes. Will it work with double quotes as well?